# Can a class detect the name of the object being instanciated

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I'd like to make a class automatically log all the objects of that class when they are instantiated, so, given this little piece of code:

```
class Comet:
    comets = []

    __init__(self, mass):
        self.mass = mass
        Comet.comets.append(**instance name as a string**)


HalleysComet = Comet(3*10**14)
Temple 1 = Comet(7.9*10**13)

print(str(Comet.comets))
```

The output would be this:

```
['HalleysComet', 'Temple 1']
```

Comment: No. Creating the instance takes place **first**, assignment only when that succeeds.

Comment: Also, objects do not necessarily end up being assigned to a name. What about `some_list = [Comet(), Comet()]`?

Comment: Also, objects do not necessarily end up being assigned to a single name. What about `Halleys = Shoemaker = Comet()`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet

Comment: You could make your class associate names with instances by making the `coments` class attribute a dictionary and adding a `name` argument to the `__init__()` method. In the method you can add the value of `self` to the dictionary using `name` as its key. This isn't exactly what you asked, but may be good enough for whatever you're trying to accomplish.